# html how to set image through inspect element not working

Tags: html, inspect-element

I want to change an image through inspect element, I believe the language is html, to an image I have a url for. I'm a complete noob and here is the results from my attempt:

[inspect element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFiiR.png)

[result on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW8YM.png)

As you can see the image just comes up with a "?" i want it to be the image in a url i have how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this link, which links to an actual image (not imgur website)

```
http://i.imgur.com/pbf1Jqu.jpg
```